# Measuring memory use in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory, memory-management

I  am trying to use WMMap v3.21 (part of Sysinternals) to measure memory use by a (Mathematica) process on Windows 7. Two questions here:

1. WMMap `Help` says this, in particular:

> Viewing Changes VMMap saves each snapshot and allows you to view the
>   differences by selecting the Show Changes entry in the Options menu.

However, I see no Show Changes entry in the Options menu.

2. Sometimes, I see no differences between what WMMap shows before the beginning of a calculation and after it (even after pressing `F5` to refresh), even though the calculation must have taken a substantial amount of memory.

Any suggestions? Thank you.